# how to capture multiselect picklist value in text field using workflow

Tags: workflow, multi-select

I am trying to copy picklist value from workflow field update and when record is created and edited.
but the problem is multiselect picklist values support only include and includes function. so multi-select  values are not copying in text fields.

Even tried with formula field text but it won't worked.

There are two field
1.) Category  (Multi-select picklist) :- It contains Public, Government, Private
2) Category selected : Text field 100 character

I want to store category values suppose user is trying to create new record with category public and government then i need in Text field Catagory_Selected__c = Public;Government; (copied that category value)

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, you need a trigger for this. Doing this in a Workflow rule is at best problematic, and will require constant maintenance (every time you add a picklist value, you must also remember to update this workflow rule).